# Random service point

Tags: anylogic

I am trying for my pedestrian agent to pickup a random service point within a "service with area" in anylogic. But they pick up the closest one, Is there a way they pickup a random service point in pedService within anylogic?

Thanks,
Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

not possible

The service points choose the pedestrian as soon as the service point is free... If you want to control the service points to which the pedestrians go, you have to create your own complex logic using independent waiting areas and independent service points (in other words, not using the pedService block with a service with area as it's normally used). This will required lots of coding depending on what you want exactly.

Nevertheless if you see that one service point is never used because the pedestrians are using the one closest to them, then it's a good indicator that you don't need to have so many services in the first place.

Comment: Hi Felipe, 

Thank you so much for your expert opinion.

I am just struggling with with my pedestrian agent to get to the service point where they have maintain the maximum distance from the other pedestrians. Do you think it might be possible with the process modelling library in combination with pedSource?

Thank you once again for your response.

Thank you, Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Felipe that maybe it's not possible/easy to make peds choose service points independently. But you can try one thing (not sure whether it will work on not).

When you have a certain number of attractors in the service area, they have their individual ID, you can try to rearrange them & try to put 11,6,8,9,... (random order). Though I am not sure whether ped takes service based on ID or not.

Comment: Hi Tariq, Thanks for your insights. Thats what happening with me. The rearranging the service point attractors is not work effectuivly. They are still picking up the closest one. Thank you,

Comment: yes, I was suspecting it though. I hope that you find some solution or roundabout. Felipe may give you some good suggestion from an expert point of view.